# How can I access the Doctrine profiler in production environment?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, profiler

I have a filter set up to count the number of queries executed and write something to my database if they exceed a certain limit.

It works fine in my development environment, but when I test it in my production environment my database doesn't return a profiler anymore. I suposse it is a setting which enables the database profiler for the development environment, but I can' seem to find it.

I use Symfony1.4 and Doctrine.

```
$database = $databaseManager->getDatabase($name);
if ($database instanceof sfDoctrineDatabase && $profiler = $database->getProfiler())
{
    $events = $profiler->getQueryExecutionEvents();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force the profiler for a connection inside your database.yml with the `profiler` option:

```
prod:
  master:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      profiler: true
      dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname'
      username: username
      password: password
```

> Indicates whether to output doctrine log to the debug toolbar. The default value of profiler depends on the environment. In development environment the default value is `true`, otherwise - `false`.

Comment: @Pino but be careful with the profiler in production environment, it's not recommended to enable it since it generates lots of debug stuff that can slow down your application.